# error 404 tomcat server:The requested resource is not available

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tomcat9

I'm using tomcat server version 9.0 in IntelliJ Idea IDE. When I run the application, the server cannot show jsp pages, I don't know what the problem is.

I'm trying to create simple spring MVC project. My war file builds successfully, and it started on tomcat without errors.

But, when I do call some service, for example http://localhost:8086/appWeb/, it gives the give error:

> type Status report message description The requested resource is not available.

dispatcher-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org /schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.pluto"/>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"/>
<beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp"/>
<beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</beans>
```

HomeController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(ModelMap model){ 
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

application-Context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Application is not able to find out the requested resource basically tells that you do not have any mapping which matches the requested URL.

Try to put slash in request mapping url like below.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```